# I want to get only NON-duplicate row in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, unique

I have table:

```
+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Name  | Price | Url  | Adress   |
+-------+-------+------+----------+
| John  | Smith | blah | London 1 |
+-------+-------+------+----------+
| John  | Smith | blah | London 1 |
+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Jenny | Cole  | blah | Prague 1 |
+-------+-------+------+----------+
```

and I want to get this:

```
+-------+------+------+----------+
| Jenny | Cole | blah | Prague 1 |
+-------+------+------+----------+
```

I was trying to create sqlite command with *having*, but no result..

Comment: Add the keyword **DISTINCT**, after SELECT. For your reference:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT 'John' AS Name , 'Smith' AS Price , 'blah' AS URL , 'London 1' AS Address
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'John' AS Name , 'Smith' AS Price , 'blah' AS URL , 'London 1' AS Address
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jenny','Cole' ,'blah' ,'Prague 1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jenny','Cole' ,'blah' ,'Prague 2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jenny','Cole' ,'blah' ,'Prague 3'  
)
SELECT Name, Price, URL, Address
FROM C
GROUP BY Name, Price, URL, Address
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: I tried and I got only one result, but table has 1300 items and every second item is duplicate

Comment: IMGs: 
 
http://www.david-sykora.cz/img1.png http://www.david-sykora.cz/img2.png http://www.david-sykora.cz/img3.png

Comment: As you can see in my last 3 records, they are all the same but not in Address, So you will get the last 3.

Comment: As I can see in your attached image, you have some other columns which are not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From your_table_name
Group By Name, Price, Url, Adress
Having Count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Is possible that is problem in sqlite3?

Comment: It return the sql row. if you want to display (result) column just replace * with whatever column you want to display. But ' * ' should return every column in the table.

Comment: I know, but its not my real problem :(

Comment: http://www.david-sykora.cz/img1.png
http://www.david-sykora.cz/img2.png
http://www.david-sykora.cz/img3.png

Comment: so check if they're exactly the same you can paste the data in a word or notepad and try use find (ctrl+f) to search the match up if you are able to then the query should execute what it does because you do get the result from the unique column. remember, even if there are small changes like a character difference it also counts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select Name, Price, Url, Adress
from table t
group by Name, Price, Url, Adress
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: There is probably some subtle difference in the values -- `name`, `URL`, and `Adress` are all (presumably) strings that can have hidden and unusual characters.  In your example, one of the five that look like duplicate actually has some different character -- perhaps as simple as a space at the end.